# How to check which segue was used

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I got two segue's which lead to the same `viewController`. There are 2 buttons which are connected to the same `viewController` using 2 segues. In that `viewController` I need to check which button was clicked. So actually I need to check which segue was used/preformed. How can I check this in the viewControllers class? I know there is the `prepareForSegue` method, but I cannot use this for my purpose because I need to put the `prepareForSegue` in the class where the 2 buttons are, and I don't want it there but I want it in the `viewControllers` class because I need to access and set some variables in that class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set a variable of the second viewcontroller in the prepareforsegue method of first one. This is how it is done:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segueIdentifier1])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        if(sender.tag == ...) // You can of course use something other than tag to identify the button
        {
            secondVC.identifyingProperty = ...
        }
        else if(sender.tag == ...)
        {
            secondVC.identifyingProperty = ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can check that property in the second vc to understand how you came there. If you have created 2 segues in the storyboard for 2 buttons, then only segue identifier is enough to set the corresponding property value. Then code turns into this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segueIdentifier1])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        secondVC.identifyingProperty = ...
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segueIdentifier2])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        secondVC.identifyingProperty = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but when I put this:         PageScrollViewController *controller = (PageScrollViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.startStory = YES; the app crashes

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setStartStory:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9976420'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: The weird part is that the error says somethiing about "setStartStory" but I never used this? I use startStory

Comment: setStartStory is the automatically generated setter for your property startStory. Did you synthesize startStory?

Comment: __setStartStory__ is the setter method of __startStory__ which is automatically generated when you synthesize(automatically synthesized in latest Xcode ) the property

Comment: Yes, I did @synthesize startStory;

Comment: then can you write the line you created it in header file?

Comment: @property(nonatomic) BOOL startStory;

Comment: make that @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL startStory

Comment: The error says something about UIViewController, but the class isn't from that type...

Answer (score 2):

So firstly you need to set your segues identifier directly in storyborads or through your code using the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.
Independently the way you choosed, your view controller will fire the following method, so you need to override it to know which `segue` was sending the message, you do like this:

```
 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {    
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ButtonSegueIdentifierOne"]) {
            // button 1
        }
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ButtonSegueIdentifierTwo"]) {
            // button 2
        }
}
```