# Hide a UIViewController (Screen) in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue, xcode6.3

[image]

As you can see the screen flow as follows:

After clicking on the 'button2' of 'screen A', app shows 'screen B' from same storyboard which has a tab bar. 
After clicking on the 'red tab' of 'screen B', app shows the 'green button'(right corner).
After clicking on the 'green button' of 'screen B', app shows 'screen C'of Storyboard 2.

I need to go back to 'screen B' of 'Storyboard 1' after clicking the back button of 'screen C', no matter from where exactly 'screen C' has appeared and the 'screen C' of 'Storyboard 2' should disappear from top to bottom.

Is it possible to do so, if yes then how?

Comment: give a segue to the Screen A to Screen C. and use `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: The flow of the screen should be same. So I can not set a direct segue between screen A and screen C.

Comment: Rizwan, When screen C is displayed from screen B and we perform unwind segue after clicking the back button of screen C, it works properly as segue is coming from screen B. But  when screen C is displayed from screen A and we perform unwind segue after clicking the back button of screen C, it does not work as segue is not coming from screen B. I need to go back to screen B after clicking the back button of screen C even if it is coming from screen A.

Comment: see Edit2 . it will solve your problem

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I implement segue and add the animation and it works.

Comment: If you get better solution  . Show how u acheive this as it will help the other people. Writing a one line answer is not beneficial to other people.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can hide `UIViewController`, as your `UIViewController` is nothing but the normal `UIView`.

So just create an `@IBOutlet` for your `UIView` and use `.hidden` method 
like this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mainview: UIView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   mainview.hidden = true
}
```

**Edit**:
Correctly specify what you want to achieve. It does not matter if your display viewController is coming from screen A or B until there should be some condition OR ViewController require some input value (string, int, etc) to process it.

**Edit2**:
Refer this answer [How to check which segue was used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167425/how-to-check-which-segue-was-used)

**Edit3**:
As per your Edit answer (move to ScreenC to ScreenB whether screenC is coming from ScreenA or ScreenB) it is better to used three separate 3  storyboard and call the destination ViewController as needed.

here is code for `ViewController` class ( moving **ScreenA -> ScreenB** OR **ScreenA -> ScreenC**)

```
@IBAction func buttonAisClick(sender: AnyObject) {
// move to ScreenC directly
    var moveToNextVC:ViewController3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3

    self.presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func ButtomBisClick(sender: AnyObject) {
// move to ScreenB
    var moveToNextVC:ViewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2

    self.presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

code for `ViewController2` class( moving from **ScreenB -> ScreenC**)

```
@IBAction func ScreenBbuttonIsClick(sender: AnyObject) {
// move to ScreenC
    var moveToNextVC:ViewController3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! ViewController3

    self.presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

code for `ViewController3` class ( moving from **ScreenC -> ScreenB**)

```
@IBAction func ScreenCbuttonIsclick(sender: AnyObject) {
    var moveToNextVC:ViewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! ViewController2

    self.presentViewController(moveToNextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Rizwan, When screen C is displayed from screen B and we perform unwind segue after clicking the back button of screen C, it works properly as segue is coming from screen B. But  when screen C is displayed from screen A and we perform unwind segue after clicking the back button of screen C, it does not work as segue is not coming from screen B. I need to go back to screen B after clicking the back button of screen C even if it is coming from screen A.

Comment: Thanks Rizwan for your response, I have edited my question and its screenshot.

Comment: you still  face some problem?

Comment: Rizwan, Yes. Please see my question again and if possible please also provide some sample codes.

Comment: It is not possible. you can achieve this but u need to use 3 storyboard for that.

Comment: Can you tell me the method or screen flow? can you come on chat? it will be better for us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80876/discussion-between-amit-raj-and-rizwan-shaikh).

Comment: @Vinod Jaiswal marked as answer is not my hand. if u find this this answer as helpful u can upvote the answer