# How to detect which segue identifier activated current view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm just looking for a way to detect which Segue Identifier activated the current viewController. I'm in need of doing this as I have conditions that might not be met, but can be referenced from another viewController, which then I'd like to highlight a few labels using that specific segue ID. Has anyone needed to do this before? How did you approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check which segue was used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167425/how-to-check-which-segue-was-used)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to mitigate the needed questions on SO @DávidPásztor, however the mentioned question you linked isn't applicable to my scenario. I don't see a need for your down vote either. I had a perfectly reasonable question for the best approach to a problem that has enough variances in all situations that required my question.

Comment: You just accepted an answer that is pretty much the same as the one in the question I linked, so you have just proven my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you should create on your "current view controller" a property to store the name of the segue and then on the controller which uses the segue to instantiate your "current view controller" you assign it before fire the segue execution:

**ObjectiveC:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueName"]) {

    // Get destination view
    CurrentVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Get button tag number (or do whatever you need to do here, based on your object
    vc.segueName = @"YourSegueNam";
}}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueName"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination {
            destinationVC.segueName = segue.identifier
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you need? Let me know.
Anyway I still do not know why you want to do that.

Comment: You actually got the concept I was trying to convey. I guess my objective was a little confusing. 
Essentially I have an app that needs to be on a specific network, when the controller that validates the network; if the validation fails, I perform a segue to show the user network details. Now I wanted to highlight specific labels within the VC that shows network details that aren't correct. So the network details VC would need to understand why the validation failed so I could present relevant UI changes to inform the user why validation failed. 
But your concept answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: Just realized that @rmaddy. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanDenlinger I haven't iOS Debugger right now but I think I added a working ObjectiveC code too.

Comment: No worries! I'm fluent in both, I have the code working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot simply get the "current Segue" at any point in the app. Because Segues Exist only at specific points in time during your Apps Life cycle. That being when your app is preparing for the transition from one view controller to another and also during the actual visual transition.
For more info follow https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue